# How can i find geth.ipc path to open a new prompt?

Tags: go, blockchain, ethereum, prompt, geth

I started a new ethereum private blockchain and let it run. Now i need to interact with it while it is running. I have to open a new console and use the command `attach` with the path of the geth.ipc file but i can't find it. Can anyone help me please?
I'm new in geth and now i'm following this guide https://hackernoon.com/heres-how-i-built-a-private-blockchain-network-and-you-can-too-62ca7db556c0
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I always add `--ipcpath "/home/your_folder/geth.ipc` when run the geth command to start the network. If you did not declare this, i guess it is located (as mentioned in the website you cited) in `geth attach /path_to_your_data_directory/YOUR_FOLDER/geth.ipc`.

In my case i just need to type `geth attach` without declaring where the geth.ipc is located in the second terminal and it will open the Geth Javascript Console.

Answer (score 0):

The geth.ipc file is located in your datadir. Your datadir is where you specified in starting your private net using geth command. For example,

```
geth --datadir ./privatechain
```

The geth.ipc will be located in ./privatechain/geth.ipc.

Answer (score 0):

Came to this question after I had similar problem. In my case, I had not specified the datadir so the approach I used was to find it in the commentary at the start of the client running. You should see something like this:

```
INFO [localdate|localtime] IPC endpoint opened                 url=\\.\pipe\geth.ipc
```